# 'AppData' Folder Did Not Exist (Contains HAXM Folder)(Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, installation, haxm

I downloaded HAXM installer through Android SDK Manager, then I searched it at the local disk and did not find it.

According the Manager the location is at the 'AppData' folder that found at my local disk, but the 'AppData' folder did not exist.

C:\Users\Ofek\ **AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_accelerater_execution_manager**

the strings marked bold are the missing parts\folders

Comment: `AppData` folder is hidden by windows by default

Answer (score 0):

Download HAXM from the Intel site. -    https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Comment: How much of that string can you see after appdata - you know you'll have to turn on view hidden files and folders to see it, right?

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on your keyboard, and you will see this window:

[image]

Type`%appdata%` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then you will reach the AppData folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The Sdk Manager showed that HAXM was installed but the AVD Manager said that it was not. I tried a lot of things but nothing worked except this....

**C:\Users\Ueser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\haxm-7.6.5-setup**

**You will need to run this setup file if you want HAXM to work.**

Android Studio installation will not do this automatically!